# SQLite UPDATE Statement

Tags: sqlite

SQLite UPDATE Statement

I have two tables:

```
Table1

ID  Num
1
2
3
4
5

Table2

ID  
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
4
4
4
5
```

I need to UPDATE the Num field in Table1 with occurences of the ID field in Table2 i.e. based on previous:

```
Table1

ID  Num
1   2
2   3
3   2
4   3
5   1
```

If i run this SQLite statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(t2.ID) FROM Table1 t1,Table2 t2 WHERE t1.ID=t2.ID GROUP BY t2.ID;
```

i have the correct table but when i try to UPDATE with that statement:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Num=(SELECT COUNT(t2.ID) FROM Table1 t1,Table2 t2 WHERE t1.ID=t2.ID GROUP BY t2.ID);
```

i have nonsense output.Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You must use a [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) to correlate the value returned by the subquery with the current row in the outer query.
This means that you must not use `Table1` again in the subquery, but instead refer to the outer table (with the actual name; the UPDATEd table does not support an alias):

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Num = (SELECT COUNT(t2.ID)
           FROM Table2 t2
           WHERE Table1.ID=t2.ID
           GROUP BY t2.ID);
```